# MySQL and PHP: Get regularly dates from one starting date

Tags: php, mysql, date, calendar

**My target**: I have a starting date and want alle upcoming dates with an SQL query.

I have a simple SQL query in my calendar where I check if it is today. Is it today, the meeting from today (same date from meeting with today) is shown in the calendar.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM meetings WHERE date = '$today_date';
```

Now I have a new function, that the meeting can be single, weekly and monthly. In my database is a column where this data is stored with "e" (single), "w" (weekly) and "m" (monthly).

Now I search for a mysql query solution or a other hint to get all upcoming events with one starting date.

**For example**: The starting date ist the 28th May (this is my database entry: starting date and regularly column: weekly) and the meeting is a weekly meeting. So I want to see in my calendar an upcoming meeting at the 4th June.

Comment: If you have options for weekly, and monthly how does one define the upper limit? because, future time is infinite :) . Or, you actually have individual entries for every single meeting?

Comment: Yeah, thats the problem: there is no end for the entries and I don't want infinitely entries in my database. So I need a solution with only one entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to solve on the basis of assumptions.Since, in a Calender you will show one month at a time. If next month is clicked modify current month.Lot of pseudo code here.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM meetings WHERE date > '$today_date'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
// Get Current Month [Cur_month]
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    if($row["meetingtype"] === 'e') // single
    { 
        // Meeting data
    }
    if($row["meetingtype"] === 'w') // weekly
    { 
        // For loop from 0 .. 3
        // Display Meeting data 4 times 
        // date = date + 7;
    }
    if($row["meetingtype"] === 'm') // Monthly
    { 
        // just display for cur_month;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Umashankar, it helps me to solve the problem.

Comment: The solution: I have also a monthly calendar, but i need it first in a weekly calendar. So, my query get all meetings from today and from the past. I store the name from the calendar week day (e.g. Monday) in a variable. Then in my function I only return the meetings from the date today and where the day in the week from the calender match the same day from the meeting. Huh, a little bit complicated to explain.

Comment: Martin - if you like the answer, please do accept it and upvote the answer.